# ListView с Load more на WPF, или StackPanel и ScrollViewer, или Чем заменить вертикальный StackPanel, чтобы возвращал свою текущую высоту

Tags: c#, wpf

Так я делаю:

```
<ListView.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ListView">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListView">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer"
                                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                  Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                  Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                            <Button Content="More" Name="moreButton"></Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListView.Style>
```

но ScrollViewer начинает вести себя неадекватно. прокрутка не работает плавно по одному item'у, а воспринимает всю stackpanel как единое целое, проскакивая все элементы.

если вместо StackPanel будет Grid с фиксированной Height, то прокрутка будет работать нормально.
но Grid мне не подходит, так как высота ItemsPresenter, разумеется, заранее неизвестна

Comment: Не понятно, что вы вообще пытаетесь сделать, почему переопределяете стиль? Почему сразу не использовать тот элемент, который нужен?

Comment: можно узнать почему вы решили, что `Grid` вам не подходит?

Comment: просто не задавайте фиксированную `Height`

Comment: А если сказать `ScrollViewer`'у `CanContentScroll="false"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добрый день. Если я правильно понял вашу задачу, то вам идеально подойдет `Grid`, как написали в комментариях.

Вот исправленный пример вашего кода:

```
<ListView.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ListView">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListView">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer"
                                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                  Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                  Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ItemsPresenter Grid.Row="0" />
                            <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="More" Name="moreButton"></Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListView.Style>
```